# How to reference Vue 3 Router in component for Push Nav

Tags: vuejs3, router

I need to load new views in my  Vue3/Quasar app programmatically based on clicking HTML elements and processing the click in JS.  By most articles I am finding, the supposed way to do this is via this.$router.push(...), but $router is not there.  I thought the reference was automatically there in Vue3.

I have the router working and can navigate via typing a matching path in the URL, but when trying to implement programmatic navigation in a component there is no reference to the router instance $router.

How do I get a reference to the router from inside a Vue component?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: the code has gotten away from me.  I need to start over with minimal code and prove that I can do programmatic navigation.  vitejs is also complaining that I need to install @vitejs/plugin-vue "to handle .vue files".

l will try to post something to update what is going on when I figure it out!!!

Answer (score 0):

Without code it's hard to say, but probably you need to import router composable to use router, f.e:

```
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
...
const router = useRouter();
router.push({...});
```

Comment: I implemented the logic you suggested above., which mirrors the documentation for programmatic nav in Vue3.  I get the following:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

I have not yet found a code pattern that works for programmatic nav.

Comment: Show me the code 